# cant get select column 3 from sqlite query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I can't select column weight from sqlite 
If user and password check print weight (query) in toast
any help me ?

[image]

```
Button btnLogin;
EditText editUsername;
EditText editPassword;
TextView result;
DatabaseHelperTwinIGE databaseHelperTwinIGE;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab5twinoge, container, false);


    btnLogin = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    editUsername = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
    editPassword = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
    result = (TextView)view .findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    databaseHelperTwinIGE = new DatabaseHelperTwinIGE(getActivity());

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isExist = databaseHelperTwinIGE.checkUserExist(editUsername.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText().toString());

            if (isExist){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {
                editPassword.setText(null);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Login failed. Invalid username or password.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });


    return view;

}
}
```

---

```
public class DatabaseHelperTwinIGE extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.app.army.tab/databases/";
    private final String USER_TABLE = "user";


    public DatabaseHelperTwinIGE(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        createDb();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }

    public void createDb(){
        boolean dbExist = checkDbExist();

        if (!dbExist){
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDatabase();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDbExist(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;

        try {
            String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }


        if (sqLiteDatabase != null){
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
            return  true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    private void copyDatabase(){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            String ourFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME ;

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(ourFileName);

            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int length;


            while ((length = inputStream.read(b)) > 0 ){
                outputStream.write(b,0,length);
            }

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(){
        String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return db;
    }
    public void  close(){
        if (db !=null){
            db.close();
        }

    }


    public boolean checkUserExist(String username,String password){
        String[] column = {"username"};
        db = openDatabase();

        String selection = "username=? and password = ?" ;
        String[] selectionArgs = {username,password};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(USER_TABLE,column,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        close();
        if (count>0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

i dont want print login success
i want to print weight from sqlite query

i cant select column weight from sqlite
if user and password check print weight (query) in toast

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, we choose to select `weight` from the database. The corresponding weight will only be returned if the password and username are correct. We only select the first result.

```
public int getUserWeigth(String username, String password) {
    String[] column = {"weight"};
    db = openDatabase();

    String selection = "username=? and password = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {username, password};

    int weight = -1;

    Cursor cursor = db.query(USER_TABLE, column, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        weight = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    close();

    // if the user credentials were valid, a weight will be returned, otherwise -1
    return weight;
}
```

Then you can show `Toast` like this:

```
int weight = databaseHelperTwinIGE.getUserWeigth(editUsername.getText().toString(), editPassword.getText().toString());

if (weight > -1){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Login Success, weight = " + weight,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    result.setText(Integer.toString(weight));
} else {
    editPassword.setText(null);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Login failed. Invalid username or password.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: weight type texgxt

Comment: Then change getInt() to getString()

Comment: public int getUserWeigth(String username, String password) {
        String[] column = {"weight"};
        db = openDatabase();

        String selection = "username=? and password = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {username, password};

        int weight = -1;

        Cursor cursor = db.query(USER_TABLE, column, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            weight = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        close();

       
        return weight;
    }

    }

Comment: i change the type weight to int

Comment: can you give me your email and i will send you picture

Comment: can someone help me

Comment: @il_raffa, Mike M., macmoonshine, Garf365, Enzokie